# Laravel Store , corrupted or not all are saved on database

Tags: php, laravel, controller

```
 public function patient_aprrovedischarge(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //get patient details
        $patientDischarge =  DischargedPatients::where('id', '=', $id)->first();

        //find patient update to DISCHARGE pending
        $updatepatient = Patients::find($patientDischarge->patient_id);
        $updatepatient->user_currently_at = 'DISCHARGED';
        
        // //update discharge details
        $dischargepatient = DischargedPatients::find($id);
        $dischargepatient->status = 'approved';
        $dischargepatient->discharged_by = auth()->user()->id; 
        $dischargepatient->discharged_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        
        // //save remarks
        $dischargeRemarks = new Remarks();
        $dischargeRemarks->remarks_detail = 'Discharged Aprroved';
        $dischargeRemarks->remarks_from = auth()->user()->id;
        $dischargeRemarks->user_from_type = 'MO';
        $dischargeRemarks->patient_id = $patientDischarge->patient_id; 

        $updatepatient->save();
        $dischargepatient->save();
        $dischargeRemarks->save();

        return redirect('/medical/discharged')->with('success', 'Patient is now discharged!');
    }
```

**sorry , im not good with stack overflow, my problem is that not all of these 3 saves are on the database. its already uploaded on the hosting, maybe anyone can explain why, i think it has problem with the internet since sometimes it disconnects**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You are trying to save same record twice</strike>, basically `$patientDischarge` and `$dischargepatient` are same records.

```php
public function patient_aprrovedischarge(Request $request, $id)
{
    //get patient details
    $patientDischarge =  DischargedPatients::findOrFail($id);
    $patientDischarge->status = 'approved';
    $patientDischarge->discharged_by = auth()->id(); 
    $patientDischarge->discharged_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $patientDischarge->save();


    //find patient update to DISCHARGE pending
    $updatepatient = Patients::findOrFail($patientDischarge->patient_id);
    $updatepatient->update([
        'user_currently_at' => 'DISCHARGED',
    ]);
  

    Remarks::create([
        'remarks_detail' => 'Discharged Aprroved',
        'remarks_from' => auth()->id(),
        'user_from_type' => 'MO',
        'patient_id' => $patientDischarge->patient_id,
    ])

    return redirect('/medical/discharged')->with('success', 'Patient is now discharged!');
}
```

Comment: does that mean that the 1st line also inserts in the database? the $patientDischarge part?

Comment: Actually i checked again and you are not trying to save same record twice and your code has to be worked. You have only one mistake which you are try to retrieve same record twice.

Comment: thanks, one more thing, does calling it twice causes delays on storing? or something like consumes time?

Comment: Calling twice runs 2 sql queries and it's not necessary and consumes time. In your case not much time but still retrieving record twice not good practice.